# How to edit web part name and view of web part?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I'm running stand-alone Sharepoint Foundation 2013, I want to be able to edit the name of a web part but cannot for the life of me find anyway of doing this. I also want to change the view of a webpart just on the one page e.g. I want a calendar webpart on my home screen only showing current events rather than the whole monthly calendar.

Any help would be great, it's probably really easy but I couldn't find anything on the subjects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two different questions, first one can be done easily by going into Web Part settings.. Click the arrow that appears on the top right corner of the Web Part -> Edit Web Part.. It will display a panel on the left, where you can update the Title.. The second requirement will need some customization (AFAIK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To add a calendar with just the current events to a page, click the gear icon and you should see the `Edit page` option. It seems like SharePoint online's UI might be different from on prem. I've added an on prem screen shot to this step. On SP online go to the `Page` tab and select `Edit`.

[image]
 *  Click the `Insert` then `WebPart` => `Apps` => `Events` where Events is the name of your calendar list.

[image]

- Change the view clicking the downward arrow on the right of your screen. You might need to mouse over it to get it to be visible because MS only wants people who are initiated into the dark arts of SharePoint administration to find it.

[image]

[image]

- Then change the value of `Selected View` to Current Events. If that view does not exist, you might have to create it.

  [image]
- Then you expand the `Appearance` group (see image above) and you will see a `Title` attribute that you can change.

Comment: Are these features available in Sharepoint Foundation 2013? because i cannot for the life of me find the arrow (because unfortunately I'm not initiated in the dark arts). The only arrow i can select is a blue one that just minimises the web part.

Comment: If you can see the you don't have the correct permissions.

Comment: I'm the site administrator, surely i don't need to grant myself permissions?

Comment: All of the options I mention are available in Foundation. Let's start at the beginning. Do you see the `edit` option when you click the gear icon? It seems SharePoint Online's UI is a little different. Click the gear, if you don't see `edit` you don't have `design` permissions.

Comment: Yes I have edit page when clicking the gear in the top right hand corner.

Comment: The rest of my instructions should work once you select edit page. These have been mostly the same since 2007 and are nearly exactly the same as 2010. Remember, you have to mouse over to get the "down arrow" to edit the web part.

Comment: I have moved the mouse around the top right hand corner of the web part but nothing shows up. it just has the minimise arrows and nothing else in the corner.

Comment: What minimize arrow? Do you mean the down arrow to the left of the checkbox in my third image? When you click that you should see the same menu as my 4th image.

Comment: No it's a bold blue arrow, which only minimises the web part and does nothing else. No menu is displayed when i click this arrow. I'm using foundation SP1 if that makes any difference?

Comment: Which browser? IE?

Comment: Yeah i'm using IE

Comment: Let's switch this to email, if it's ok. Mine is my SharePoint.SE username with no spaces at gmail.

Comment: Can't find your SE username, just displays you're name? email me at my first name followed by @fulgent.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing the problem that I had (a blue arrow which only minimizes the web part) the way to resolve it is to add the site to compatibility view in Internet Explorer.

[image]

In IE11 go to settings > compatibility view

then have your site added like mine below:

[image]

this will then give you the correct view in which you can edit your web part.

Comment: That just seems odd. I'm using IE 11 as well. I can't imagine why it was behaving this way.